# Mmap new file to existing pointer instead of munmap

Tags: go, mmap

I am using mmap on Go, after `mmap` a file, this pointer will be used across all goroutines.

Then i want to update this file data (with new size + data layout) if i `munmap` it, it will cause segfault error if any other goroutine access to the freedmemory region.

Then i don't use `munmap`, i create a new file with updated data then i `mmap` this file on the old pointer, will it work or cause any memory leak?

```
// mmap a file
b, err := syscall.Mmap(fdOldFile, 0, int(dataSize), syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_WRITE, syscall.MAP_SHARED)

// mmap new file with new size
nb, e := syscall.Mmap(fdNewFile, 0, int(newSize), syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_WRITE, syscall.MAP_SHARED)

// pooring data to new file with new data layout
// ...


// munmap b will cause segfault if b is beging used in another goroutine
// syscall.Munmap(b)

os.Remove(oldFile)
os.Rename(newFile, oldFile)
syscall.Munmap(nb)

// set b = new b instead
b = syscall.Mmap(fdNewFile, 0, int(newSize), syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_WRITE, syscall.MAP_SHARED)
```

Comment: Please provide the code. Without it, it is much harder to help you.

Comment: @mbuechmann code is provided

Comment: `b` will be garbage collected by the runtime, if there are no references to it. I guess you can safely use `nb`. You don't have to manage it explicitly like in C or other languages

Comment: `b` will be used across the goroutines, this is the simple code layout, `b` will be killed if the program is terminated, thats why i got segfault after calling munmap

Comment: @Inian b will not be collected, golang tracks all mmaped addresses internally in a map https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux.go#L2076. You have a few challanges when doing this, first is that the `address` parameter can't be set in the Mmap function given to use (it is always 0). Growing or shrinking of an existing mmap can be done with the `mremap` syscall, but there is no existing syscall wrapper in the syscall package. So to do stuff like this you will have to make your own syscall wrapper using `syscall.Syscall` and the `unsafe` package

Answer (score 1):

The code in your example will keep the old file memory mapped, this is because the kernel will keep it mapped until you unmap it or the process exits. Because of this the syscall/sys library always [keeps a reference](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/17980dff368256a0763cf042376d3fb36d06c109/src/cmd/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux.go#L2070) to the memory mapped address to prevent it from being garbage collected, even if you lose the reference.

The proper way to replace the file behind the same address is to use the `mmap` syscall with the same address. However, the `syscall.Mmap` wrapper will not let you specify the `address` param, it is always 0(which means that the kernel will pick a address not currently in use).

You can also grow or shrink the existing region with the `mremap` syscall, but no wrapper exists for this syscall in the stdlib. The most likey reason for these limitations it that when you change an existing mapping, the length may change. Go will return a []byte, which internally has a cap and len value. So if the size of the underlaying array changes but the len will not you can get segfaults. And since the len and cap are passed by value, the stdlib can't change these slices when changing the underlying memory.

So, in order to do this, assuming you still want to you have to:

1. Expose the internal syscall.mmap function which does allow you to specify `address`

```golang
import _ "unsafe"

//go:linkname mmap syscall.mmap
func mmap(addr uintptr, length uintptr, prot int, flags int, fd int, offset int64) (xaddr uintptr, err error)
```

2. You should still use `syscall.Mmap` for the initial allocation of the address because there are a few requirements and it is better to let the kernel pick a good addresss, but now you can change it. You will need to use reflection and unsafe pointer casting to get the address form the []byte you got back from `syscall.Mmap`.
3. If you are going to pass a different `length` you must also the change
   the `len` of all copies of the []byte including subslices to avoid segfaults. If you use the exact same length every time this should not be an issue.

So TLDR: You need to be very sure what you are doing to not make any mistakes or you will some nasty bugs, but it can be done.

Comment: my goal is simple, to munmap the old file then mmap the new file to replace, i wonder using mutex to lock `b` during using munmap will save the other goroutines from segfault?

Comment: Yes it will, the segfaults occur because after unmapping the process no longer has access, thus segfaulting on read. If you can guard reads and writes to `b` with a mutex or RWMutex then you should be good.

Comment: after examine `set b = new b` solution, i don't see the memory leak or system keep old file memory mapped, don't know if the old file is removed or change file content will solve this issue or not, i've updated the code to complete the flow, same file name, just don't use munmap